# Відповідник до слова "скотч"

Tags: вживання-слів, from-english

Із статті [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Клейка стрі́чка або ***скотч*** (англ. Adhesive tape) — плівкова стрічка з клейовим покриттям, що застосовується в побуті та на виробництві; технологічно використовує фізичне явище адгезії.

[Українсько-англійський словник ділової людини 2014 (Є. І. Гороть, О. В. Василенко, Н. В. Єфремова та ін.)](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=Adhesive%20tape&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on)

> ***Adhesive tape***
>   стрічк||а ім. ж.  тех. tape
>
> • ізоляційна ~а adhesive tape
>
> • клейка ~а (скотч) sticky tape

На сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/skotch) пропонують замінювати на *липок, липучка, налипач, клейка стрічка, липач*

В СУМ-20 є визначення *[липучка](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=47501&page=1499)*, зокрема знач.2 найбільш схоже, але не є повним відповідником до слова *"скотч"*. 
Інші запропоновані замінники в СУМ-20 відсутні.

Яке із слів краще використовувати в діловому мовленні? Чи можемо використовувати слово ***"скотч"*** в документах чи краще замінити на словосполучення ***"клейка стрічка"***?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У [Найповнішому тлумачному словнику української мови](https://eslovnyk.com/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87) знаходжу слово "скотч" без жодної зазначення, звідки випливає, що слово літературне і необмежене у використанні:

> **скотч** а, ч. Тонка стрічка з липким шаром, яка використовується для пакування дрібних предметів тощо.

У [Словнику іншомовних слів](http://www.jnsm.com.ua/cgi-bin/u/book/sis.pl?Article=16795&action=show) подають теж без використання будь-якої позначки:

> **Скотч** (2) власна навза Scotch ***плівкова стрічка з клейовим покриттям.*** *Від назви торгової марки компанії 3М.*

У [Словнику синонімів](http://getword.ru/ukr/slovari.php?word=%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87&table=ukr_syn_2) подають споріднене словосполучення, про яке і Ви пишете:

> **клейка стрічка.**

Виходячи з усього, роблю висновок, що:

1. СУМ-11 не подає слова ***"скотч"***, оскільки воно відносно нове.
2. СУМ-20 не подає цього слова, оскільки ще наразі виданий до літери "М", тому, можливо, ще бути містити і таку статтю, оскільки він сучасний.
3. Оскільки в академічних виданнях немає цього слова (принаймні я не знайшла), то з вище навадених вважаю, що лексему скотч можна використовувати у діловому мовленні, однак це буде запозиченням на кшталт *унітаз, ксерокс*, які теж утворені від назв фірм, що виготовляли ці товари.

Однак не буде помилкою і вживання словосполучення, що подає словник синонімів, "***клейка стрічка***".

P. S. : мені, наприклад, варіант "клейка стрічка" більш до вподоби! :-)

Comment: Додам, що [«Словники України on-line» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) містять слово «скотч» у значенні «клейка стрічка». Містить його й [ВТССУМ](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/скотч). Містить його й література на [Google Книгах](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=скотч&lr=lang_uk) (художня й інших видів).

Answer (score -2):

Слово «скотч» є епонімом утвореним від назви бренду клейкої стрічки. Вживання його для позначення довільної стрічки є правильним приблизно настільки, наскільки правильним є вживання слова «памперс» до довільного підгузника, чи «ксерокс» для довільного копіра: широковживаним, загальнозрозумілим, але все ж некоректним. Тому в діловому мовленні я б надав перевагу загальнішій назві «клейка стрічка». Навіть, якщо мова йде про клейку стрічку бренду Scotch.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/). Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою. Для цього натисніть [edit].

Comment: Я б погодився. Але практика переходу назв брендів поширена не лише в українській мові (_джакузі_, _пінг-понг_, _тефлон_, _унітаз_, _фризбі_), а й у світі (_hoover_, _Jacuzzi_ тощо) — й у ній немає нічого поганого. Питання лиш у тому, чи достатньо вже це слово поширилося в ролі загальної назви, чи це все ще нечасте й суто розмовне явище.

Comment: Напевно останнє речення повинно бути без "не": "Навіть, якщо мова йде ПРО клейку стрічку бренду Scotch" - тобто, "навіть коли це товар з брендом "Скотч", я б все одно вживав вираз "клейка стрічка".

Comment: Oksanka S. дала вичерпну відповідь з посиланнями на всі можливі словники, тому @bytebuster, я щиро не розумію, яких джерел у цій відповіді вам бракує? Копіпасти, чи посиланнь на сайти 3M, Procter&gamble та Xerox?

Comment: Особисто я вважаю Вашу відповідь не зовсім повною, бо не розумію, чому Ви порівнюєте «скотч» із «памперс», суто розмовним, а не, приміром, із «унітаз» чи «фризбі», що вважаються нейтральними (та й у некоректності «ксерокса» я не впевнений — деякі словники вже наводять його без позначок «розм.», «сленг», «рідко» абощо). Але «мінуси» ставив не я. Якщо Ви вважаєте, що для Вашої відповіді цілком досить джерел з ін. відповіді (мовляв, просто Ви по-іншому їх інтерпретуєте), то, можливо, можна зазначити, на які саме дж. з ін. відповіді Ви спираєтеся й у якому плані (щоб не докучали «де джерела?»).